# Detecting when there's space left for only one row and when a new page is added with FPDF

Tags: php, fpdf

In this project I'm using FPDF to generate PDF files with tables. I managed to get the table structure set but I want to add table head and table footer whenever is needed.

Code:

```
<?php
function tableTitle($pdf){

    $pdf -> SetFillColor(214, 214, 214);
    $pdf -> Cell(28, 5, utf8_decode('MATRÍCULA'), 1, 0, 'C', 1);
    $pdf -> Cell(106, 5, utf8_decode('NOME'), 1, 0, 'C', 1);
    $pdf -> Cell(28, 5, utf8_decode('CPF'), 1, 0, 'C', 1);
    $pdf -> Cell(28, 5, utf8_decode('MÉDIA'), 1, 0, 'C', 1);
    $pdf -> Ln();
}

function tableBody($pdf, $matricula, $nome, $cpf, $media) {
    
    for ($i=0; $i 100< ; $i++) { 
    //For testing purpose, data input will come later
    
    $pdf -> Cell(28, 5, utf8_decode($matricula), 1, 0, 'C');
    $pdf -> Cell(106, 5, utf8_decode($nome), 1, 0, 'C');
    $pdf -> Cell(28, 5, utf8_decode($cpf), 1, 0, 'C');
    $pdf -> Cell(28, 5, utf8_decode($media), 1, 0, 'C');
    $pdf -> Ln();

    }

}

tableTitle($pdf);
tableBody($pdf, "55555/20", "LOREM IPSUM DOLOR SIT AMET", "xxx.xxx.xxx-xx", 10.00);


$pdf -> Output();
?>
```

The tableTitle() is function that creates the row that I need to be added.

Comment: FPDF has [GetY](http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/gety.htm), which returns the current vertical position. If you know the height of the row you're adding and the height of the page, you can calculate if there's room for that row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I detect whether or not a table row is going to spill to the next page:

```
if (($ourpdf->GetY() + ($linecount * 5)) > $ourpdf->pagebreak) {  // data won't fit on this page

    $ourpdf->AddPage();   // page break
    pcs_Header($ourpdf);  // add the table header
    $fill = true;         // force next row of table to be filled

}  // end of not enough room for the data on this page
```

And this is the `pcs_Header` function that is called to output a fresh table header when needed.

```
function pcs_Header($ourpdf) {

    $ourpdf->SetWidths([43,28,25,20,30,25,13,23]);
    $ourpdf->SetAligns(['C','C','C','C','C','C','C','C']);
    $fill = false;
    $ourpdf->SetFont('','',10);
    $ourpdf->Row(['PCS Name'        ,
                  'PCS ID'          ,
                  'PCS Type'        ,
                  'PCS Risk Rating' ,
                  'Street Address'  ,
                  'City'            ,
                  'Zip'             ,
                  'County'],0,true);

}  // end of the pcs_Header function
```